# duplicated menu module in joomla

Tags: menu, joomla3.0

I have a bottom menu module in my joomla CMS which works fine in footer 1 position. However, when I try to create another menu module in the footer 2 position. it assigns the same articles to this menu item as my first one?

Answer (score 0):

You go to folder "template/{name of template}" and open file "index.php". Then create new module menu footer:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('footer_menu')): ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer_menu" style="none" />
 <?php endif; ?>
```

After that, you go to backend and config position.